# a python code for getting the sum of every digit in an integer is not properly working

Tags: python

A simple python code for getting sum of every digit in n integer. I tried a while to get the number of digit and for loop to get the sum. Sometime it's working. But sometime it's giving one less. like 22222 should be 10. But i am getting 9.

```py
import math

def number_adder():
    number = int(input('Enter a natural number: ', )) #Inputs user value. Specifically a natural number

    sum = 0

    number_of_digit = 0
    for digit in str(number):
        number_of_digit += 1            # getting number of digit in the input value

    number = number * 10 ** (-number_of_digit + 1)

    sum += math.floor(number)
    number -= math.floor(number)

    for digit in range(number_of_digit - 1):
        number = number * 10
        sum += math.floor(number)

        number -= math.floor(number)

    print('The sum of all digits of the value is, ', sum)


number_adder()
```

Comment: `sum(int(x) for x in str(n))`

Comment: And don't use `sum` as a name for a variable. You stomped on the function `sum()` when you did

Comment: you already iterate over digits `for digit in str(number):` and then you are finding the number of digits which is not needed as you can just do `len(number)` and again if you are iterating of `str(number)` just add `int(digit)` to some variable and that is your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum the digits of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939953/sum-the-digits-of-a-number)

Comment: But I want to know what is troubling my code. Why is it giving error

Answer (score 2):

You are making this *way* too complicated.

Just do:

```
>>> n=22222
>>> sum(int(x) for x in str(n))
10
```

And

```
>>> n=12345
>>> sum(int(x) for x in str(n))
15
```

Explanation:

```
sum(int(x) for x in str(n))
                     ^  turn the number into a string
                     ^  strings are iterable character by character  
     ^       ^       ^  a comprehension loop to loop over those 
     ^       ^       ^  characters
               ^        each character assigned to x
      ^                 turn x back into a integer 
 ^                      sum all those digits together
```

Here is a less terse example:

```
n=123456
total=0
for ch in str(n):
    print(f'{ch:>3}')
    total+=int(ch)
    
print(f'===\n{total:>3}')
```

Prints:

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
===
 21
```

Comment: I really don't see how that answers the question... There are obviously many ways to do that, the OP is asking what is wrong with __their approach__...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it even more compactly by using the `map()` function which in this case, applies the `int` function to every string representation of each digit, then each `int` digit is being summed by the `sum()` function.

**Sidenote**: Please don't use `sum` as a variable name because it's a built-in function, and you are shadowing it.

```
def number_adder():
    #Inputs user value. Specifically a natural number
    number = int(input('Enter a natural number: '))
    num_sum  = sum(map(int, str(number)))
    print('The sum of all digits of the value is', num_sum)

number_adder()
```

Output (with an input of `22222`):

```
Enter a natural number: 22222
The sum of all digits of the value is 10
```

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

```py
def number_adder():
    # [...]
    
    sum += math.floor(number)
    number -= math.floor(number)
    print(number)
    # Prints: 0.22219999999999995

    # [...]
```

I added a `print` statement to check the value of `number` out and given the input `22222` the output for `number` at that point was: `0.22219999999999995`. That happens because `Python` doesn't execute floating point operations with infinite precision, so that's the most precise value it can get for the substraction given `sum` and `number`.
(Check [Python error in basic subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120340/python-error-in-basic-subtraction) and [Python error in basic subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120340/python-error-in-basic-subtraction) as examples).

Naturally, when looping through the `decimals` of `number` the following happens:

```py
for digit in range(number_of_digit - 1):
  number = number * 10
  sum += math.floor(number)

  number -= math.floor(number)
```

```
0.2221999...5 <-- Adds a 2
0.221999...5 <-- Adds a 2
0.21999...5 <-- Adds a 2
0.19999...5 <-- Adds a 1
```

And that's the reason why you get 9 as the final number (Adding up to the previous value of 2).

### Possible solution:

Replace `number -= math.floor(number)` in the two lines that I point out with `number = round(number - math.floor(number), number_of_digit - 1)` to get back the original decimal values by rounding

```py
import math


def number_adder():
    # [...]
    sum += math.floor(number)
    # Round number to `number_of_digit - 1` decimals 
    # This will yield: `0.2222` for the original input `22222`
    number = round(number - math.floor(number), number_of_digit - 1) # (1) <---

    for digit in range(number_of_digit - 1):
        number = number * 10
        sum += math.floor(number)
        # Round `number` again here as this is a new floating point operation 
        # (number_of_digit - digit - 2) are the remaining decimal points
        number = round(number - math.floor(number), number_of_digit - digit - 2) # (2) <---

    print("The sum of all digits of the value is, ", sum)
```