# Adding decimal numbers to a decimal number not working properly in python

Tags: python, numbers, decimal

I'm trying to add decimal numbers a decimal number and it works correctly but when I do `1.1 + 0.1` I get `1.2000000000000002` but all I want it to equal to is `1.2`. When I do `1.0 + 0.1` I get `1.1` which is perfect but i don't get that for `1.1 + 0.1`. So is there a way that I can get rid of the `000000000000002` from `1.2000000000000002`?

Thanks.

Comment: See [Python math is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11950951)

Answer (score 7):

As has been stated countless times, 0.1 cannot be represented exactly in IEEE 754 floating point. You can read all about why in [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

You can trucate or round the value:

```
>>> round(1.1+.1,2)
1.2
>>> "%.*f" % (1, 1.1+.1 )
'1.2'
>>> s=str(1.1+.1)
>>> s[0:s.find('.')+2]
'1.2'
```

If you want *exact* representation of those values, consider using the [Decimal module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('1.1')+decimal.Decimal('.1')
Decimal('1.2')
```

Note that you need to start with the string representation of your float, `'0.1'` since `0.1` is not exactly representable in binary in IEEE floating point:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(.1)
Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')
```

To then get a string representation back after you calculate, you can use `str`:

```
>>> str(sum(map(decimal.Decimal,['.1','.1','.5','.5'])))
'1.2'
```

Another alternative is to use a rational number library such as [Fractions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction as Fr
>>> Fr(11,10)+Fr(1,10)
Fraction(6, 5)
```

With that result, you will still need to round, truncate, or use an arbitrary precision arithmetic package to get an exact number (depending on the inputs...)

Answer (score 3):

You can try string formatting, [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

```
>>> "%0.2f" % float(1.1 + 0.1)
'1.20'
```

Or Even:

```
>>> "%0.1f" % float(1.1 + 0.1)
'1.2'
```

As to why, it is explicitly described on [PEP 327 here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0327/#from-float).

Answer (score 0):

This is the literal answer to your question:

```
float(str(1.1 + 0.1)[0:3])
```

If you're interested in the "why" of the problem then refer to the links provided in the question comments.

Comment: Or the much simpler approach
`round(1.1 + 0.1, 2)`