# Why .05+.01 == .06 return False in python 2.7.3?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As per my expectation .05+.01 should be equal to .06 but in python its not happening.
As `.05+.01 = 0.060000000000000005` and that is not equal to `.06`.

```
>>> .01+.01
0.02
>>> .02+.01
0.03
>>> .03+.01
0.04
>>> .04+.01
0.05
>>> .05+.01
0.060000000000000005  #expected .06
>>> .06+.01
0.06999999999999999  #expected .07
>>> .07+.01
0.08
>>> .08+.01
0.09
>>> .09+.01
0.09999999999999999 #expected .10
>>> 0.09999999999999999+.01
0.10999999999999999  #expected .11
```

what is the reason for this?

Comment: Obligatory: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This was already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950819/python-math-is-wrong

Answer (score 9):

Because Python uses [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) floating point numbers, which are not perfectly precise. The iconic example is `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004`.

This is [well documented](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in the Python docs.

Answer (score 4):

The values you're working with are floating point numbers, see also: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 4):

Because `0.01` and `0.05` are not what they are looking:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(0.01)
Decimal('0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375')
>>> decimal.Decimal(0.05)
Decimal('0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125')
```