# Strange addition of numbers, why?

Tags: javascript

Doing:

```
 0 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
```

In Safari and Chrome results in:

```
 0.30000000000000004
```

At least when displayed as a string, for example:

```
 console.log( 0 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 );
```

Making the string assumption because the following returns 4:

```
 0 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Your question is really not clear - you say, "displayed as a string", but there are no strings in the code you posted.

Comment: See also [Python math is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950819/python-math-is-wrong), though the question is about python the answer is same

Comment: @Pointy console.log prints a string representation of a Number yeah?