# inequalities issue: 0<=-0.0 is not true

Tags: python, zero, inequalities

I have an if statement within a for loop which runs through a number values of x and calculates a value of h based on the x. I have included the code below. At time zero (`t=0.0`) `xa=-0.0` and `xb =0.0`.

The problem arrises when `x=0`. At `x=0` I want the code to follow the first `if` statement as `x` is less than or equal to `0`. However it doesnt it goes to the last if statement and carries that out. Now my thinking is that the problem is something to do with `x= 0` and `xa=-0.0` and python doesn't like this?

If anyone could shed any light on the subject as to why this occurs and if there is a solution to the problem or if indeed there is a different problem, that would be great.

```
__author__="ahe"
__date__ ="$05-Aug-2014 11:22:44$"

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math 
import sys
from math import sqrt  
import decimal
import pylab 

nx, ny = (100,100)
x5 = np.linspace(-2000,2000,nx)
y5 = np.linspace(0,600,ny)
xv,yv = np.meshgrid(x5,y5)
x = np.arange(-2000.0,2001.0,1.0)
print len (x)

h0=0.03
g=9.81
t=0.0

term1=4.0/(9.0*g)
term2=math.sqrt(g*h0)
print 'term1=',term1,'term2=',term2 

xa=-term2*t
xb=term2*2*t

h=np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range (len(x)):
   if x[i]<=xa:
      h[i]=h0
   elif (xa<x[i]<xb):
      h[i]=term1*((term2-(x[i]/(t*2.0)))**2.0)
   else:
      h[i]=0


print 'xa=',xa,'xb=',xb

h1=np.zeros(len(x))

f = open(r'C:\opentelemac\bluetang\examples\telemac2d\ritter\4D0.i3s', 'r')
while True:
   line = f.readline()
   if line[0] not in [':','#']: break
ran = int(line.split()[0])
length = np.zeros(ran)
wse =  np.zeros(ran)
for i in range (ran):
   fields = f.readline().split()
   length[i] = float(fields[0])
   wse[i] = float(fields[2])
   all =[length[i],wse[i]]

print x[1995:2005]
print h[1995:2005]



plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(length,h, marker='o', linestyle='--')
plt.plot(length,wse)
plt.legend(['Analytical solution_0','Model_0'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure you have exactly `0` and `-0.0`?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point. I suspect that the xa variable, "-0.0", is an actual value that is close to zero, but is a minuscule amount less than zero. For example, '-0.00000000000000000000000000001" and the debugger and python print statements just render it as "-0.0".  Hence, the expression `0 <= xa` isn't actually true.

Comment: Try debugger and see, what is value of `x[i] - xa`. It is definitely not zero.

Comment: Ok thanks for the swift replies, that makes sense. I will try the debugger. Is there a way of estbalishign what the number is exactly rather than the rounded version of the number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11950951/674039

Comment: Ok when i = 2000 (x=0). x[i] - xa = 0.0. Thoughts @JanVlcinsky

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I do floating point comparison?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison)

Comment: Ive resolved the issue now with the help of the floating point comparison link. Im new to python and was searching for a different problem, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is true

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0 <= -0.0
True
```

So you probably did not diagnose your problem correctly.

Comment: @user3771983 Bartosz told it very well - you shall invest some effort into how to diagnose problems.
Very good debugger intro is at [PMotW - pdb](http://pymotw.com/2/pdb/index.html).