# sum of [0.0,0.7,0.2,0.1] do not equal to 1

Tags: python, numpy

The some of 0.7,0.2,0.1

```
sum([0.0,0.7,0.2,0.1])=0.99999999999999
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Although [Python math is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11950819) is popular too. :-P

Comment: It's a common problem in all programming languages due to the impossibility to store certain floating-point numbers. [Here][1] are more information.


  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: And of course [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Read one of the introductory tutorials first, but eventually read this too.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Use Decimal for accuracy `from decimal import Decimal \n sum([Decimal('0.0'),Decimal('0.7'),Decimal('0.2'),Decimal('0.1')]) = Decimal('1.0')`