# int multiplication with float = WHAT?

Tags: python

The snippet below seems very very very strange to me. The result should be -3.6.. Some rounding failure or have i missed something here?

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:45:13) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> -5.0+float(14)*0.1
-3.5999999999999996
>>>
```

Comment: Perfectly normal behaviour of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: See also this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: welcome to the [secret club](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11950951/674039) !