# Why 10 // .01 = 999.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why not 1000 ? The result is `float`, because of '*Semantics of True Division*' in [PEP238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), but `math.float(999.999999999999999) = 1000`. That is confusing. I have the assumption, that actually answer is something like 999.9999999123564384, but how to check it? And `10 / .01 = 1000.0` btw.

Comment: Because 1/10th cannot be accurately represented in a floating point number. You are not dividing by ten. You are dividing by 10 and a little bit more.

Comment: And [Python math is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950819/python-math-is-wrong)

Comment: Use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)s if you want that to be true. Floating point is binary.

Comment: Decimal(10) // Decimal(0.01) = Decimal(999) too

Comment: `Decimal('10')//Decimal('0.01')` --> `Decimal('1000')`

Comment: You need to pass a string into `Decimal` - `0.01` is the already inaccurate float (the closest float representable value to 1/100), so `Decimal(0.01)` is the Decimal representation of that value. Passing a string lets it see the true base 10 value.

Comment: This also gives a neat way to see the true value of a float: print the Decimal of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0.1` is *not* exactly one-tenth.

Floating point numbers are binary approximations; just as a decimal number is represented by a sum of 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16, etc, a float is a sum of binary fractions, 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16, with bits switching on or off each of those fractions in the sum. You can only ever *approximate* one tenth, but the real value becomes apparent when you format the value with more digits:

```
>>> format(0.1, '.55f')
'0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625'
```

That uses the following fractions:

```
>>> fractions = []
>>> sum = 0.0
>>> for i in range(1, 56):
...     fraction = 2 ** i
...     if sum + (1.0 / fraction) <= 0.1:
...         fractions.append(fraction)
...         sum += 1.0 / fraction
... 
>>> fractions
[16, 32, 256, 512, 4096, 8192, 65536, 131072, 1048576, 2097152, 16777216, 33554432, 268435456, 536870912, 4294967296, 8589934592, 68719476736, 137438953472, 1099511627776, 2199023255552, 17592186044416, 35184372088832, 281474976710656, 562949953421312, 4503599627370496, 9007199254740992, 36028797018963968]
```

`//` gives you *floor* division, and multiplying 1000 by *slightly more* than 1/10th gives you *slightly less* than 100, so that is floored to 999.