# How can I apply a format to a groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I have the following DataFrame:

```
      High  counts   Total
11  1.2492       2  2.4984
1   1.2466       2  2.4932
20  1.2574       1  1.2574
19  1.2547       1  1.2547
18  1.2523       1  1.2523
```

I have used following line to groupby

```
hg = grps.groupby("High").size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

I am trying to group by this DataFrame in the following format. But values of High must not change.

```
{:.3f} # 1.249, 1.246, 1.257 ...
```

Is it possible to do this or shall i create a new DataFrame?

**EDIT**:

Here is the expected output

```
      High  counts   Total  New
11  1.2492       2  2.4984  1.249
1   1.2466       2  2.4932  1.246
20  1.2574       1  1.2574  1.257
19  1.2547       1  1.2547  1.254
18  1.2523       1  1.2523  1.252
```

Comment: You say you want to group by that (yes it is possible) but what do you want out of it?  If you aggregate, you end up with fewer rows than you started with.  In that case, how shall you choose among the multiple possible rows?  You may want to transform?  You haven't told us what you want in the end.  And that is a critical part of this problem.

Comment: Actually i did. The following line is the output: {:.3f} # 1.249, 1.246, 1.257 ...

Comment: @DonCoder - Do you need `df['New'] = df['High'].map('{:.3f}'.format)` ? Or `df['New'] = df['High'].round(3)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html) with [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) to convert values to numpy array multiple by number of values after float point and last divide same value:

```
N = 3
df['New'] = np.floor(df['High'].values * 10 ** N) / 10 ** N
print (df)
      High  counts   Total    New
11  1.2492       2  2.4984  1.249
1   1.2466       2  2.4932  1.246
20  1.2574       1  1.2574  1.257
19  1.2547       1  1.2547  1.254
18  1.2523       1  1.2523  1.252
```

Another solution:

```
df['New'] = (df['High'].values * 10**N).astype(int) / 10**N
```

Fast comparison:

```
#[5000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [213]: %timeit df['New1'] = df['High'].map(truncate)
8.27 ms ± 667 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [214]: %timeit df['New1'] = np.floor(df['High'].values * 10 ** N) / 10 ** N
220 µs ± 2.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @DonCoder - Glad ca help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom formula utilising `math.floor` and `pd.Series.map`.

```
import math

def truncate(f, n=3):
    return math.floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

df['New'] = df['High'].map(truncate)

#       High  counts   Total    New
# 11  1.2492       2  2.4984  1.249
# 1   1.2466       2  2.4932  1.246
# 20  1.2574       1  1.2574  1.257
# 19  1.2547       1  1.2547  1.254
# 18  1.2523       1  1.2523  1.252
```

Note you may still face issues with [floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950819/python-math-is-wrong) since you are beginning with `float` data.